# Any posts/articles evaluating the prevalent and double-edged "Google for it first, think later!" practice?

Tags: discussion

Trying to find posts/articles (or even the right SE forum!)  where people have evaluated the prevalent and double-edged "programming by just googling for it" practice in terms of its detriment to practicing to be a better programmer.

Knee-jerk answers might as well be entirely opinion-based so resisted the urge to post it as a **non-meta** question ... so rather, wanted to see if any respected pundit/s did any evaluation/study of this trend or if a prior post (didn't have much luck finding it) contained **somewhat** objective analysis?

Comment: Just as a note, you may find that [chat] would be a good place to ask - both in looking for existing questions and if you are indeed looking for a bit of discussion on the subject.

Comment: SE doesn't have forums.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about Programmers Stack Exchange or the software that powers the Stack Exchange [network](http://stackexchange.com/sites) within the scope defined in the [help center](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From our own (and I'm not digging too deeply):

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63504/would-a-cut-and-paste-coder-ever-get-past-a-job-interview
- [Does over-reliance on tools imply that you are lazy?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/88745/does-over-reliance-on-tools-imply-that-you-are-lazy)

Outside of that... we're a poor substitute for google.  And please remember, we're not a forum.

Comment: `we're a poor substitute for google` - Very...  Even for known content, I often use `site:foo.stackexchange.com bar baz` on Google instead of the site's search.  It seems to work better.